# Why is this jQuery code not working correctly in Firefox?

Tags: jquery, firefox

In Chrome, this code works just fine. But in Firefox - it does not. I'm stuck...

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var score = 0;

$('.left').hide();
$('.right').hide();

$("#score h2").html("What emotion is being shown?").hide().fadeIn('slow');

$('.happy').click(function(){

    if($(this).hasClass('happy') && $(".thegame").find("img:eq(1)").hasClass("happy")){
    $('.left').show();
    $('.right').show();
    score++;
    $(numbz).html(score);
            setTimeout(trolli,3000);
    function trolli(){

         sadgame = $('.thegame').html('<div class="pic"><img class="left" src="img/sadness02.jpg"/ ></div><div class="pic"><img class="sadness" src="img/sad03.jpg"/ ></div><div class="pic"><img class="right" src="img/sadness01.jpg"/ ></div>');
        $('.left').hide();
        $('.right').hide();
       $("h2").removeAttr('id', 'canswer').html("What emotion is being shown?").hide().fadeIn('slow')};

        $("h2").attr('id', 'canswer').html("You are correct! Happiness looks the same on everybody!").hide().fadeIn('slow');
    } else if(!$(".thegame").find("img:eq(1)").hasClass("happy")){
        $("#score h2").attr('id', 'wanser').html("You are not correct! Try again.").hide().fadeIn('slow');
        score--;
        $(numbz).html(score);
    };


});
```

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
    <title>
        facetest.com
    </title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="answers">
        <div class="sadness">
            <p class="feelings">SADNESS</p>
        </div>
        <div class="anger">
            <p class="feelings">ANGER</p>
        </div>
        <div class="surprise">
            <p class="feelings">SURPRISE</p>
        </div>
        <div class="fear">
            <p class="feelings">FEAR</p>
        </div>
        <div class="disgust">
            <p class="feelings">DISGUST</p>
        </div>
        <div class="contempt">
            <p class="feelings">CONTEMPT</p>
        </div>
        <div class="happy">
            <p class="feelings">HAPPINESS</p>
        </div>

        </div>

        <div class="thegame">
            <div class="pic">
                <img class="left" src="img/happy-man.jpg"/ >
            </div>
            <div class="pic">
                <img class="happy" src="img/happy-woman.jpg"/ >
            </div>
            <div class="pic">
                <img class="right" src="img/happy-celeb.jpg"/ >
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="score">
            <h2 class="emoz">What emotion is being shown?</h2>
            <h3 class="playmeist">Score: <div id="numbz">0</div> pts.</h3>
            </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Again, this code works just fine in Chrome. But not in Firefox. Why is that?**
It just keeps giving me 1 point for clicking happiness every time. But only in Firefox.

Comment: How exactly does it not work?

Comment: It just keeps giving me 1 point for clicking happiness every time. But only in Firefox.

Comment: Correctly indenting your code would make it a lot easier to read.

Comment: I'm new to programming in general and especially jQuery. Sorry @Cody.

Comment: Take a look at the site in question: http://facetest.info

Comment: Can you strip it down to just enough code to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you launch firebug in Firefox you can see the problem.  It isn't finding your trolli function.

Try moving that function and your score variable outside the scope of your document.ready call.

Comment: I took a look and updated my answer.  See if that helps? Not sure why it is different in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a lot of problems with this code. Here it is working:

http://jsfiddle.net/8vdmb/4/

The biggest issue here is you are missing a }. Notice there is a function trolli(){ and then the next } is just before an else if, which means you never ended your function. I'm not exactly sure where you wanted to end it, but I took a good guess. Then you also didn't close the document.ready(function(){....you need to learn the power and tabing out your code, so you can see which brackets aren't close. Also a good ide that will point this out very quickly is good too. Another thing that was wrong was settimeout was trying to call a function that wasn't defined yet, so I moved it after where it was defined.

Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var score = 0;

    $('.left').hide();
    $('.right').hide();

    $("#score h2").html("What emotion is being shown?").hide().fadeIn('slow');

    $('.happy').click(function(){

        if($(this).hasClass('happy') && $(".thegame").find("img:eq(1)").hasClass("happy")){
            $('.left').show();
            $('.right').show();
            score++;
            $(numbz).html(score);

            function trolli()
            {
                 sadgame = $('.thegame').html('<div class="pic"><img class="left" src="img/sadness02.jpg"/ ></div><div class="pic"><img class="sadness" src="img/sad03.jpg"/ ></div><div class="pic"><img class="right" src="img/sadness01.jpg"/ ></div>');
                $('.left').hide();
                $('.right').hide();
            }
            setTimeout(trolli,3000);
            $("h2").removeAttr('id', 'canswer').html("What emotion is being shown?").hide().fadeIn('slow');

            $("h2").attr('id', 'canswer').html("You are correct! Happiness looks the same on everybody!").hide().fadeIn('slow');
        }
        else if(!$(".thegame").find("img:eq(1)").hasClass("happy")){
         $("#score h2").attr('id', 'wanser').html("You are not correct! Try again.").hide().fadeIn('slow');
          score--;
          $(numbz).html(score);
        };


    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Every place you have `$(numbz)`, change it to `$('#numbz')`.